# Moment generating of Log-Normal distributed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

As is well known, for any log-normal distributed random variable $Y$, the moment generating function $$M(t)=E[e^{tY}]$$ does not exist for any t>0.

**Question:** What about the case if t<0? Can I find the largest domain of $t$ such that the function $M(t)$ exist? What would be its value?

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Characteristic_function_and_moment_generating_function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum it up : $M(t)$ exists whenever $t\leq 0$ because $Y$ is almost surely positive. There is, however, no known closed form for $M(t)$.

Source : [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Characteristic_function_and_moment_generating_function).

Comment: Could you explain bit more why $Y$ being almost surely positive would induce that the expectation is finite?

Comment: If $Y$ is almost always positive and $t\le 0$ then $tY\le 0$ and hence $\exp(tY)\le 1$ a.e., and hence integrable.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks!